# Android app - debug log data sorted by user available realtime for customer service purposes

Tags: android, firebase, amazon-cognito

We are using Firebase today for crash logging and some debugging. However for the production app we are looking for the best way to achieve the following scenario;

1. Customer calls in with a problem, it might be with one of the embedded devices the app communicates with or the app itself.
2. Agent logs in to a service, selects the user account (AWS Cognito) and fetch a human readable log of the latest actions and settings done on that particular users account.

Are any of the known services today made for this to happen in an easy way? Seems most is focused towards debugging, but this is more a production intent and to be able to help customers in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce Firebase Analytics to the app and then distinguish user by setting user ID: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid

I think you'll need some work on adding the analytics logs for the actions in the app you want to track